Neutralino: issue with two apps side-by-side
I am using neutralino to create small helpful desktop apps (all taking place under Windows 11).
But sometimes, I have an issue, when multiple apps are open and I want to close one of them.
Steps to reproduce:

I start the first App by double click on its desktop icon
I start the second App by double click on its desktop icon
I try to end the second App ( "Neutralino.App.exit()" is called by a button )

The first App gets terminated. The second App's window is also closed, but I can still see the process in task manager.
first App's neutralion.config.json:

"port": 0,
"tokenSecurity": "one-time",
"exitProcessOnClose": false

second App's neutralion.config.json:

"port": 63976,
"tokenSecurity": "none",
"exitProcessOnClose": false

I changed port numbers both to "0". -> no change
I started the second App by directly double click on its *.exe file (not using its desktop shortcut) --> the issue does not appear!
What is going on? How can starting a App by using its desktop icon change its behavior so rapidly?

I think, I found a sketchy workaround.
I changed the desktop icon.
Instead of starting the *.exe directly, it starts a batch - file with

start "" "path to *.exe"

instead.
